# SQL SELECT query causing different column error

Tags: php, mysql, html, sql

i am trying to sort out the mail trash section of my site and it is proving troublesome, i had problems with the query before and finally got it to work, but now the pagination is also causing trouble, i am getting this error

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Arken\pagination\function.php on line 9
SELECT COUNT(*) as `num` FROM user_inbox WHERE user_inbox.receiver_user_id='4' AND user_inbox.mail_deleted ='1' UNION SELECT * FROM user_outbox WHERE user_outbox.sender_user_id='4' AND user_outbox.mail_deleted ='1'

The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns
```

The code surrounding line 9 looks like this

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as `num` FROM {$query}";
        $row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query)) or die($query."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());;
        $total = $row['num'];
```

Line 9 being the `mysql_fetch_array` line

My user_inbox table looks like this

```
+------------+---------------+------+-----+----------+
| Field             | Type          | Extra          |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+----------+
| message_id        | int(11)       | auto_increment |
| receiver_user_id  | int(11)                        |
| receiver_username | varchar(255)                   |
| sender_user_id    | int(11)                        |
| sender_username   | varchar(255)                   |
| mail_subject      | varchar(255)                   |
| mail_message      | text                           |
| mail_date_sent    | datetime                       |
| mail_viewed       | enum('0','1')                  |
| mail_deleted      | enum('0','1')                  |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+----------+
```

And my user_outbox table looks like this

```
+------------+---------------+------+-----+----------+
| Field             | Type          | Extra          |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+----------+
| message_id        | int(11)       | auto_increment |
| sender_user_id    | int(11)                        |
| sender_username   | varchar(255)                   |
| receiver_user_id  | int(11)                        |
| receiver_username | varchar(255)                   |
| mail_subject      | varchar(255)                   |
| mail_message      | text                           |
| mail_date_sent    | datetime                       |
| mail_viewed       | enum('0','1')                  |
| mail_deleted      | enum('0','1')                  |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+----------+
```

I would really appreciate any help you guys can give, its been nearly 2 days trying to sort out this part of the site and i need to get it done.
Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your use of UNION returning a different number of columns.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as `num` FROM user_inbox ...
UNION
SELECT * FROM user_outbox ...
```

You can get MySQL to total the row count for you:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `num`
FROM
(
     SELECT * FROM user_inbox ...
     UNION ALL
     SELECT * FROM user_outbox ...
) AS your_table_alias
```

Or:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_inbox ...) +
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_outbox ...) AS `num`
```

Answer (score 3):

The second part of the query (after UNION) should also have COUNT(*).

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as `num` FROM user_inbox WHERE user_inbox.receiver_user_id='4' AND user_inbox.mail_deleted ='1' UNION SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM user_outbox WHERE user_outbox.sender_user_id='4' AND user_outbox.mail_deleted ='1'
```

Comment: @MarkByers - Not twice. 1st part on Inbox, 2nd part on Outbox.

Comment: OK, sorry, I didn't notice it.

Comment: Hi, i tried your answer and it seemed to work, but it for somereason messes all the pagination up, so for example i have 3 tabs (inbox, outbox and trash) if the trash has two pages(pagination) it shows the first page fine, but then when i click to go to the next page it just transports me to the inbox tab, which it shouldn't

Comment: My solution/answer is for the mysql error.Please verify your PHP logic for the pagination.Update the question or Post a new question with pagination logic.

Comment: @user1136379: I don't think this answer is correct. Have you looked at my answer yet? Why did you think my answer is not correct? Can you give an example of where it fails?

Comment: @Mark Byers I tried your code and it worked, but i decided to completely change my tables and now it works much cleaner than it did before, so thanks for all the help. The only problem that i am facing now is that all my inbox, outbox and trash is inside tabs, so when i click on page 2 for trash it sets all the inbox, outbox and trash to page 2, not sure how to get round this?

Answer (score 0):

You should do more research on the query "$query". Looks like you are selecting different number of columns in the query that you have defined for the variable "$query" in your PHP (I presume) code (At least the error says that).